# C# MVC ASP.NET DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I would like to send the selected dropdown option into model.Feit
Assuming, i need DropDownListFor, then select table, then the dropdown..?

```
//here's my drop down menu in my controller
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Owner", Value = "0", Selected = true });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Leader", Value = "1" });
ViewBag.items = items;
//this works fine, but the selected option has to be inserted into my database when  submitted




 //the first line shows the label
 <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Feit)</div>
 //the second line needs to show as a dropdownlist with the 2 options above here
 <div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Feit, "items")</div>
 //when the option is selected, and submit is pressed this has to be sent to the db
 // this works for all other fields, but my syntax is wrong at , "items"
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: At the top there's a dropdown list (in the controller)

At the bottom (in my create.cshtml page) there needs to be a dropdown menu with those options. These, when selected have to be put into model => model.Feit.

However i think my syntax is not right around the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already populated an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in your viewbag, you just need to access it and cast it to ensure the correct DropDownListFor overload is used:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Feit, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.items)
```

`model.Feit` should be of type `int` or something that can hold the value of the selected item.

Comment: Right, the dropdown works now.. haven't tested if it actually sends it to the DB, but i assume it will.

Thanks so much Aaron!

Comment: Errormessage: "The ViewData item that has the key 'Feit' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'."

I also tried string, doesn't work. Any other suggestons?

Comment: @user3712713 Show your ViewModel containing the `Feit` declaration and exactly what your `DropDownListFor` declaration looks like.

Comment: I dont know what I did, but i fixed it, and its working like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Feit, new SelectList(ViewBag.items, "Id","Name"),"Select")
```

Comment: ""does not contain a property with the name 'Id'"".
What exactly does "id" refer to in your example, the first option on the dropdown?

Comment: They are just Option Labels?Did you used the above code?isn't it working?

Comment: Those are not just labels, those are actually the names of properties.  When you specifiy `"Id"`then it expects that each item in `View.items` contains an `.Id` property.